# Error when increase the max_result_window in elasticsearch using a python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to increase the max_result_window in elasticsearch using a python. Here is my code:

```
elastic_client = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}], timeout=800)

elastic_client.indices.put_settings(index="studentvle",body= {"index" : {"max_result_window" : 8609436}})

total_docsstudentvle = 8609436
responsestudentvle = elastic_client.search(
    index='studentvle',
    body={},
    size=total_docsstudentvle
)
```

However, suddenly my elasticsearch stopped, and I got an error as below when I run the code:

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x005DF1A8>: Failed to
establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x005DF1A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because
the target machine actively refused it)
```

Another code as below I got from cmd elasticsearch before it stop:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to data\java_pid15608.hprof ...

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ticker-schedule-trigger-engine"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "elasticsearch[DESKTOP-8MLV90U][generic][T#4]"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "elasticsearch[DESKTOP-8MLV90U][generic][T#5]"
Heap dump file created [1482063561 bytes in 345.992 secs]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the exception from Elasticsearch, it looks like Elastic simply ran out of available memory, reaching ["OOM error"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) state

Assuming your system has enough memory, you may be able to fix this by assigning a larger heap, which appears to be 1G by default:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html

```sh
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4000m -Xmx4000m" ./bin/elasticsearch
```

If this still doesn't work, you will likely need to settle for a smaller result window and further paginate the results yourself:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after